# unhide excel sheets from dropdown with password

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to develop a code where I can have a dropdown list of sheet names which I want to unhide with a password. I have tried a lot but got no success.

Suppose, I have a multiple sheets by names, "A", "B", "C", up to "F". When I select one or multiple sheet names from dropdown box, it should prompt for password to unhide sheet. Please suggest the best way to do so.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As String)
Dim Target As String, msg As Variant

Set Target = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

If Target.Visible = False Then
msg = Application.InputBox("Password", "Password", "", Type:=2)
If response = "pgdb" Then
Target.Visible = True
Target.Select
Else
Target.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks. Made below changes in code, but getting Error 9 "Subscript out of range" after assigning the value to Target variable. Please advise.

```
'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim msg As Variant, sh As Range

Target = Sheets("Sheet32").Range("A1")
sh = Target.Value

If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = sh Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False
msg = Application.InputBox("Password", "Password", "", Type:=2)
If msg = "pgdb" Then
Application.sh.Visible = True
Application.sh.Select
Else
Application.sh.Visible = False
End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Note that this kind of password "protection" is not secure and can easily be ticked. You cannot make something secure by hiding it.

Comment: I have tried below code, but not getting any response not even an error.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments (it gets unreadable). Instead [edit] your original question and put it there, including of a description of what you expect it to do.

Comment: I am trying to put the code in my original post, but not able to succeed. Please guide me how to do so.

Comment: You put the result of your input box into the variable `msg` but you check the variable `response` for beeing the password? That can't work. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` to not run into such issues again.

Comment: Also note that it must be `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)` don't change the event's declarations. They need to be exactly as in the documentation ([Worksheet.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)). Further a range object `Target` has no `.Visible` method. You cannot use `Target.Visible`. Don't `Dim Target As String` if the variable `Target` is already used by the event `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)`

Comment: you are not allowed to assign something to the `Target` variable `Target = Sheets("Sheet32").Range("A1")`. `Target` is automatically assigned to the cell that changed. Please read the documentation of the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change). Also if you get errors you need to explain in which line of code you get them, otherwise we cannot know that.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting error in line-3, where I specified the value to Target variable, which I got to know now that is not a correct way. Could you please help me by sharing the code to solve this issue, as I am totally getting lost in it and by seeing the working code only can understand. Appreciate your great support.

Comment: Change it to `Set sh = Sheets("Sheet32").Range("A1")` and remove the line above. Also remove tha `Application.` infront of the `Application.sh`. I cannot write a full answer yet since we need to wait for the community to re-open the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look something like below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)     
    Dim DropDownCell As Range
    Set DropDownCell = Me.Range("A1") 'me points to the workbook the code is written in

    If Not Intersect(DropDownCell, Target) Is Nothing Then  'run the following only if the DropDownCell is part of (intersects) with the changed cells (Target) 
        Dim PasswordInput As Variant
        PasswordInput = Application.InputBox("Password", "Password", "", Type:=2)
        
        If PasswordInput = "pgdb" Then
            Dim SheetToUnhide As Worksheet
            On Error Resume Next  'next line throws error if sheet does not exist. Hide all error messages from now.
            Set SheetToUnhide = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DropDownCell.Value)
            On Error Goto 0  're-enable error reporting (or you won't notice any further errors if they occur.

            'note that SheetToUnhide is Nothing here if the workbook with the name of the drop down value does not exist.

            If Not SheetToUnhide Is Nothing Then 'sheet exists
                SheetToUnhide.Visible = True
                SheetToUnhide.Select
            Else  'sheet does not exist
                MsgBox "Sheet '" & DropDownCell.Value & "' does not exist.", vbCritical
            End If
        End If
    End If    
End Sub
```

Note that this procedure `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` runs every time any cell gets changed in the worksheet. `Target` reprecents cell that was changed. Note that `Target` is a `Range` and can be multiple cells (if multiple cells get changed at the same time eg. by copy/paste).

This line `If Not Intersect(DropDownCell, Target) Is Nothing Then` makes sure the code runs only if the drop down cell was changed, and not on **every** cell change.

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked as I was desiring. I will try to understand the logic and learn something. Many thanks again :).

Comment: @FirasathHussain If you have questions about it just ask. Please mark this answer as solution if it soved your issue.